# setError displays text in flyout instead of below the EditText

Tags: android, textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I'm following [this guide](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/errors.html#errors-app-errors) to display the error and [this doc](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) to implement it. It works fine but instead of displaying errors below the EditText I have them floating above with the warning icon.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
<style name="error" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/accent</item> <!--apply the color you wat here -->
    <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
</style>


<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPhoneNumber"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Phone Number" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


txtPhoneNumber.setError("Invalid Format");
```

How can I make errors to be displayed below the EditText?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass **[TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html)** Object there .

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
   android:id="@+id/txtLayout">
   .........    
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**Then**

```
  txtLayoutOBJ.setError("Invalid Format");
```

Comment: oh, I should use layout, not edittext, cool

Comment: @AlexeyStrakh Yes . Use `TextInputLayout` instead of `TextInputEditText`

Answer (score 1):

```
TextInputLayout til = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.text_input_layout)
til.setError("Your Error");
```